# What is "POSNR" an abreviation or acronym for?

Tags: sap-erp, sap-data-dictionary

I'm working with some data that's coming out of an SAP system.  There's a field named

```
POSNR
```

that appears to be a line item/database identifier of some kind.  What is this an abbreviation for?  It's not hyper-critical to what I'm doing, but every time I stare at the word it looks like pure gibberish and can be slightly distracting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not an SAP expert but could it be "[Item number of sales document](http://help.sap.com/saphelp_crm40/helpdata/en/e2/654b15a9f411d184ec0000e81ddea0/content.htm)"?

Comment: Yep, that definitely looks like the role its playing in these feeds. Of course, I don't see the letter P in there :)

Comment: This is almost certainly correct.  The actual abbreviation is going to be for something in German.  Depending on the database table its comoing from, it might just be 'Item number of the document' rather than sales doc, but that's what SAP uses POSNR for.

Comment: Yep POSNR is "Positionsnummer des Vertriebsbelegs" which Google Translate says is "Position number of the sales receipt".

I found it on this German webpage -- http://help.sap.com/saphelp_45b/helpdata/DE/e2/654b15a9f411d184ec0000e81ddea0/content.htm)

Comment: It's a german abbreviation. POS is for position, NR is our version of the english # or No. and commonly replaces the word "Nummer"

Answer (score 5):

Position number?

Answer (score 1):

If you look at, for example, VBAP table in german, POSNR is "Positionsnummer des Vertriebsbeleges" so yes, POSNR is POSition NumbeR.

It's very common in SAP tables to use it in combination with doc. number to create the primary key for positions or subdocuments, especially in SD (sales) tables. So you have VBAK-VBELN for purchase order header and VBAP-VBELN + VBAP-POSNR for items in purchase orders. So on in LIKP/LIPS, VBRK/VBRP, VBUK/VBUP...